# How to display list items on console window in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a `List` that contains all databases names. I have to display the items contained in that list in the Console (using `Console.WriteLine()`). How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 100):

Actually you can do it pretty simple, since the list have a `ForEach` method and since you can pass in `Console.WriteLine` as a method group. The compiler will then use an implicit conversion to convert the method group to, in this case, an `Action<int>` and pick the most specific method from the group, in this case `Console.WriteLine(int)`:

```
  var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 50));

  list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Works with strings too =)

To be utterly pedantic (and I'm not suggesting a change to your answer - just commenting for the sake of interest) `Console.WriteLine` is a method group. The compiler then uses an implicit conversion from the method group to `Action<int>`, picking the most specific method (`Console.WriteLine(int)` in this case).

Comment: To be utterly pedantic (and I'm not suggesting a change to your answer - just commenting for the sake of interest) "Console.WriteLine" is a method group. The compiler then uses an implicit conversion from the method group to Action<int>, picking the most specific method (Console.WriteLine(int) in this case).

Comment: Yeah, like I said, "if I got my wording correct" :p Updating the answer (let me know if I got it wrong again!)

Comment: But how to print a 2D list using this method?

Comment: list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x + ",")); using an anonymous function is way cleaner and makes it possible to add a separator to the output. Otherwise, you just have a mash of numbers. This is almost always needed for debugging reasons so performance is not what we're after here.

Answer (score 51):

While the answers with `List<T>.ForEach` are very good.

I found [`String.Join<T>(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) method more useful.

Example :

```
List<string> numbersStrLst = new List<string>
            { "One", "Two", "Three","Four","Five"};

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", numbersStrLst));//Output:"One, Two, Three, Four, Five"

int[] numbersIntAry = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Console.WriteLine(String.Join("; ", numbersIntAry));//Output:"1; 2; 3; 4; 5"
```

Remarks :

If separator is **null**, an empty string (`String.Empty`) is used instead. If any member of values is **null**, an empty string is used instead.

`Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)` is a convenience method that lets you concatenate each element in an **IEnumerable(Of String)** collection without first converting the elements to a string array. It is particularly useful with Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) query expressions.

This should work just fine for the problem, whereas for others, having array values. Use other overloads of this same method, [String.Join Method (String, Object[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx)

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This is very useful if you want to put the elements of the list inside another string like:
Console.WriteLine($"i can write here {String.Join(", ", list)} and here");

Answer (score 35):

Assuming the items override `ToString` appropriately:

```
public void WriteToConsole(IEnumerable items)
{
    foreach (object o in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

(There'd be no advantage in using generics in this loop - we'd end up calling `Console.WriteLine(object)` anyway, so it would still box just as it does in the `foreach` part in this case.)

EDIT: The answers using `List<T>.ForEach` are very good.

My loop above is more flexible in the case where you have an arbitrary sequence (e.g. as the result of a LINQ expression), but if you definitely have a `List<T>` I'd say that `List<T>.ForEach` is a better option.

One advantage of `List<T>.ForEach` is that if you have a concrete list type, it will use the most appropriate overload. For example:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };

integers.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
strings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

When writing out the integers, this will use `Console.WriteLine(int)`, whereas when writing out the strings it will use `Console.WriteLine(string)`. If no specific overload is available (or if you're just using a generic `List<T>` and the compiler doesn't know what `T` is) it will use `Console.WriteLine(object)`.

Note the use of `Console.WriteLine` as a method group, by the way. This is more concise than using a lambda expression, and actually *slightly* more efficient (as the delegate will *just* be a call to `Console.WriteLine`, rather than a call to a method which in turn just calls `Console.WriteLine`).

Comment: How to use this for complex object types say List<Person> where Person contains only string properties.

Comment: @Koder101: You'd probably want to override `ToString` in `Person`.

Answer (score 22):

You can also use List's inbuilt foreach, such as:

```
List<T>.ForEach(item => Console.Write(item));
```

This code also runs <strike>significantly</strike> faster!

The above code also makes you able to manipulate Console.WriteLine, such as doing:

```
List<T>.ForEach(item => Console.Write(item + ",")); //Put a,b etc.
```

Comment: *Significantly* faster? That sounds very unlikely to me, as the bottleneck will be the console output rather than looping.

Comment: haha I can take that word out. It is just because List<T>.ForEach is faster because it has only one method call per iteration vs standard foreach which has 2 callvirt IL instruction calls

Comment: Yes - it's certainly more efficient, just not significantly. It's always worth bearing in mind where the bottlenecks really are :) You can make the first version even more efficient using Console.Write as a method group, btw... (You can't do that with the second, as you're actually manipulating the parameter.)

Comment: Heh, yeah that is a fair claim. I forfeit mine :)

Answer (score 18):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join<TYPE>("\n", someObjectList));
```

Comment: This worked best for me as I  can prepare my string before sending it to the console, instead of sending one line to the console every time

Answer (score 0):

I found this easier to understand:

```
List<string> names = new List<string> { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five" };
        for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(names[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we need to view some data in command prompt which are coming from a database table. First we create a list. Team_Details is my property class.

```
    List<Team_Details> teamDetails = new List<Team_Details>();
```

Then you can connect to the database and do the data retrieving part and save it to the list as follows.

```
            string connetionString = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=your DB name;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString)){
            string getTeamDetailsQuery = "select * from Team";
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getTeamDetailsQuery, conn))
                    {
                        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    {
                        teamDetails.Add(new Team_Details
                        {
                            Team_Name = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Team_Name")),
                            Team_Lead = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("Team_Lead")),
                        });
                    }
```

Then you can print this list in command prompt as follows.

```
foreach (Team_Details i in teamDetails)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(i.Team_Name);
                            Console.WriteLine(i.Team_Lead);
                        }
```