# list find all elements

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I making a hashtable(not really important I think), I wanna print out all my elements from my variabel linked list, the insertionOrder(it holds strings, but doesn't matter), I have to do like this, in my method i want to return insertionOrder, but not sure how to do that so the method get all the elements, and in my class Program I wanna print out the insertionOrder, I can't find a solution, thanks! Why I have to do like this? my teacher want it like this. I just wonder if you know a solution. Thanks!

```
class Hashtable
{
    private LinkedList<object> insertionOrder = new LinkedList<object>();
    .
    .
    public LinkedList<object> GetInsertionOrder()
    {
        return insertionOrder;
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Hashtable hT= new Hashtable(8);

        Console.Writeline("The elements: " + hT.insertionOrder());         
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/how-to-display-list-items-on-console-window-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Why are you using a LinkedList? What are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: My teacher want it like this. I just wonder if you know a solution. I have much more code, but I don't think it's relevant right now. But it should be like this, you can modify it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

A few things;

`insertionOrder` is declared outside the main class, as private, so you're not going to be able to get to it from `Main()`.

`insertionOrder` has absolutely nothing to do with the `Hashtable`. I'm surprised your IDE isn't throwing up an error at the `hT.insertionOrder()` call, since it's not valid.

Try something like this.

```
class Program
{
    private LinkedList<object> insertionOrder = new LinkedList<object>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 1;
        foreach (object o in insertionOrder)
        {
            Console.Writeline("The Element(" + count + "): " + o.ToString());
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't add all my code, I have added some code now

Comment: OK, have you tried compiling what you've given here? `insertionOrder()` is not a method available to the Hashtable class, it's a field, which would mean you access it like so: `hT.insertionOrder`. That's just going to print out the object definition though. Please add in the Hashtable constructor and perhaps what your expected output is.