# List not printing out information when called in main

Tags: c#, list

I have a List called

```
private List<Car> Cars; //Car is another class
```

I want to create a new list from the information in the List< Car > Cars that  uses parameters to specify a year range to extracted from the Cars list and then placed into a new list called

```
private List<Car> getCars;
```

The code is as follows. Please note it is only part of a project so not all code is provided.

```
    private List<Car> Cars;
    private List<Car> getCars;

    public List<Car> GetCars(int fromYear, int toYear) 
    {
        getCars = new List<Car> { };
            foreach (Car c in Cars)
            if (c.Year >= fromYear && c.Year <= toYear)
                getCars.Add(c);
        return getCars;
    }
```

The problem I'm having is although there are no errors showing up when I run the code the new list does not print out, instead it print's out
  System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Lab__2.Car]

Any help would be great in how to make it print out the list's objects instead of what is above. Finally My lecturer has specified that he wants the method formatted as such

```
public List<Car> GetPrices(int year)
{
}
```

Comment: What print do you expect?

Comment: How are you calling `GetCars()`? It returns a `List<>` object. My guess is you are calling `.ToString()` on the collection itself.

Comment: You may find this useful: [How to display list items on console window in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/how-to-display-list-items-on-console-window-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You don't show the code which actually tries to print. Something like `foreach(var c in carlist) { Console.Out.WriteLine("Make: " + c.Make + ", Model: " + c.Model + ", Year: " + c.year + Environment.Newline);`? Edit: Or better the advice in @soon 's link; define a ToString() method for a car and then just print each car as an entity. Edit2: Define an extension method for List<T> which does that for any T.

Comment: You might want to print the names of the cars by iterating through the list. calling tostring on the list will print its type.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is the output you get when you call print directly on a list. It won't automatically print the contents, you must print each item yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are surely calling the `ToString()` method directly on the List but it will only print its type:

> Default implementations of the Object.ToString method return the fully qualified name of the object's type. - [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

So, you must iterate through the items in the list and print it's details. Example:

```
foreach (Car c in Cars) {
     Console.WriteLine(c.Name); //I do not know what properties you have in the class Car. Change accordingly.
}
```

Or you can use `String.Join()`:

```
String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Cars); //You can change 'Environment.NewLine' to ", " if you want a comma instead of a new line.
```

Comment: To ensure encapsulation, rather override the `ToString()` method of the `Car` class, instead of directly accessing puplic members.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines:

```
public Class Car
{   // guessing here
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public override string TosString()
    {
        return "Make: " + Make + ", Model: " + Model + ", Year: " + year;
    }
```

And then, somewhere in your program:

```
foreach(var car in CarList.Where(c => c.Year >= fromYear && c.Year <= toYear))
{ 
    Console.Out.WriteLine(car);
}
```

Note how the functionality of your `GetCars()` can be expressed in a fairly readable Linq Where method call applied to the list.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ciara specified, you must print each item yourself. When you issue something like `Console.WriteLine(car)` in your code, the `Console` class automatically calls [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method on your `Car` object.

The documentation for `ToString()` method on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies:

> The default implementation of the ToString method returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object [...]

In your case, that name is `System.Collection.Generic.List'1[Lab__2.Car]`. To change what `ToString()` method returns, in your `Car` class override the method:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("Make: {0}, Year: {1}", Make, Year);
    }
}
```

Afterwards you need to iterate the list and print each item:

```
carList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the items of the list by iterating over them, and printing each object individually:

```
for (Car car in Cars)
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.ToString);
}
```

Doing this `Console.WriteLine(Cars)` will only give you information about the `List` object, usually being the full type and maybe the address in memory, depending on the runtime.

If you want to print the items of the list after getting them from a method, do this:

```
for (Car car in GetCars(fromYear, toYear))
{
    Console.WriteLine(car.ToString);
}
```

When printing an object that is not a `string` (or other character sequence) you might want to override the ToString method that is inherited from `Object` in order to specify the information of the object (or `Car` in this case) you want to print.