# Unable to print whole list to console

Tags: c#, .net, list

Keep getting the following message when printing a list on console.

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

This is the console code. It is designed to generate a Fibonacci sequence of a given length. I have tried using the ToString() method, but that doesn't work either. I have built the algorithm in Java so i know that the issue, is fundamentally a C# problem. The issue is resolved if print i print the list elements individually, but i can't print the whole list.

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();


        Console.WriteLine(fibo.getSequence(9));

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

class Fibonacci
{

    public List<int> getSequence(int length)
    {
        List<int> results = new List<int>();

        results.Add(1);
        results.Add(1);

        int counter = 0;

        while (counter != length - 2)
        {
            int num1 = results[results.Count - 1];
            int num2 = results[results.Count - 2];

            results.Add(num1 + num2);
            counter++;
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display list items on console window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/how-to-display-list-items-on-console-window-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to print the object directly to console try iterating over list and print them wherever returned.

```
for (var item in returned) 
   Console.WriteLine(item)
```

if using a custom Type. keep in mind that you have defined its to string method.

Comment: How is this the answer? Adrian's is a much more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a `List<int>`. To print it, you have to e.g. iterate over it

```
foreach(var i in fibo.getSequence(9)) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Or you can use `String.Join()`

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", fibo.getSequence(9)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `Main()` to read:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Fibonacci fibo = new Fibonacci();

            foreach(var element in fibo.getSequence(9))
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(element);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

### Explanation

Look at what you're passing to `Console.WriteLine()` in your example. `getSequence()` is returning a list, so you're passing a list to `WriteLine()`. WriteLine will `ToString()` on the collection which, by default, will render out the type. If you pass it each individual element (`int`), it will call `ToString()` on each one and give you the number.

This is based on the assumption that you want a line per element. If not, look into using `String.Join`