# I got a problem with a simple List in C#(not displaying the actually list)

Tags: c#

```
List<int> MyList = new List<int>();
MyList.Add(1);
MyList.Add(2);
MyList.Add(3);
MyList.Add(4);
foreach(int item in MyList){
    System.Console.WriteLine(MyList);
}
```

This is what my code shows :

```c
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/how-to-display-list-items-on-console-window-in-c-sharp

Comment: Just print the number: `System.Console.WriteLine(item);`

Comment: you had a loop for each 'item' in the list so you need to work on item, not 'MyList'. print item instead of 'MyList'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display list items on console window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759133/how-to-display-list-items-on-console-window-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you are using foreach for display list objects but you trying to write list object.. change  System.Console.WriteLine(MyList); to  System.Console.WriteLine(item);

Answer (score 0):

When you `ToString` an object (which is what `Console.WriteLine` does), and it hasn't overridden `ToString()` it writes the name of the class. However, you can just use `item` which looks like a simple mistake

```
var myList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

foreach (var item in myList)
   System.Console.WriteLine(item);

// or, you can get fancy with string.Join

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", myList));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change `MyList` to `item` to show each item in `MyList` variable.

```
foreach(int item in MyList){
    System.Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
```