# How to see array or list in console tap (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How to see Array or List in console tap?
Is there the way to see them in console tap?
I want
`Debug.Log(array) -> [1,2,3,4]`

Comment: In general please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    Debug.Log(array[i]);
}
```

Almost the same for the list. Or if you need a single-line variant

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(array[i]);
    sb.Append(" ");
}
Debug.Log(sb.ToString());
```

Comment: why so complicated? [`string.Join`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36614277/7111561) already solves this ;) For exactly OP's format: `Debug.Log($"[{string.Join(",", array)}]");` ([fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVxXUV))